# Map Two Tables With Third Table Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-test

I am working on Nhibernate and I have two classes name Customer and CusotmerRole with their mapping(CustomerMap and CustomerRoleMap). Now I want to map these two tables with the Third Table we have in Database named As Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping. The Table Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping have two Columns in the database one Is Customer_Id(Primary key as well as ForeignKey with Customer Table and another is CustomerRole_Id which is also PrimaryKey and Foreign Key with CustomerRole table. So I want to know that How can I map Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping with Customer and CustomerRole. Also I need to ask that I have to create another map for this or I can map these existing classes. Thanks in Advance.

Code:

Customer.Cs :

```
public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    private ICollection<ExternalAuthenticationRecord> _externalAuthenticationRecords;
    private ICollection<CustomerRole> _customerRoles;
    private ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> _shoppingCartItems;
    private ICollection<RewardPointsHistory> _rewardPointsHistory;
    private ICollection<ReturnRequest> _returnRequests;
    private ICollection<Address> _addresses;

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor
    /// </summary>
    public Customer()
    {
        this.CustomerGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.PasswordFormat = PasswordFormat.Clear;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the customer Guid
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Guid CustomerGuid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the username
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the email
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the password
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the password format
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int PasswordFormatId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the password format
    /// </summary>
    public virtual PasswordFormat PasswordFormat
    {
        get { return (PasswordFormat)PasswordFormatId; }
        set { this.PasswordFormatId = (int)value; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the password salt
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the admin comment
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string AdminComment { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the customer is tax exempt
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool IsTaxExempt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the affiliate identifier
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int AffiliateId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the vendor identifier with which this customer is associated (maganer)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int VendorId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the customer is active
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the customer has been deleted
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the customer account is system
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool IsSystemAccount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the customer system name
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string SystemName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the last IP address
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string LastIpAddress { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time of entity creation
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time of last login
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DateTime? LastLoginDateUtc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time of last activity
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DateTime LastActivityDateUtc { get; set; }

    #region Navigation properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets customer generated content
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ExternalAuthenticationRecord> ExternalAuthenticationRecords
    {
        get { return _externalAuthenticationRecords ?? (_externalAuthenticationRecords = new List<ExternalAuthenticationRecord>()); }
        protected set { _externalAuthenticationRecords = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the customer roles
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerRole> CustomerRoles
    {
        get { return _customerRoles ?? (_customerRoles = new List<CustomerRole>()); }
        protected set { _customerRoles = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets shopping cart items
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems
    {
        get { return _shoppingCartItems ?? (_shoppingCartItems = new List<ShoppingCartItem>()); }
        protected set { _shoppingCartItems = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets reward points history
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<RewardPointsHistory> RewardPointsHistory
    {
        get { return _rewardPointsHistory ?? (_rewardPointsHistory = new List<RewardPointsHistory>()); }
        protected set { _rewardPointsHistory = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets return request of this customer
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ReturnRequest> ReturnRequests
    {
        get { return _returnRequests ?? (_returnRequests = new List<ReturnRequest>()); }
        protected set { _returnRequests = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default billing address
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default shipping address
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets customer addresses
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses
    {
        get { return _addresses ?? (_addresses = new List<Address>()); }
        protected set { _addresses = value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

CustomerRole.cs:

```
 public  partial class CustomerRole : BaseEntity
    {
        private ICollection<PermissionRecord> _permissionRecords;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the customer role name
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the customer role is marked as free shiping
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool FreeShipping { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the customer role is marked as tax exempt
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool TaxExempt { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the customer role is active
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool Active { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the customer role is system
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool IsSystemRole { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the customer role system name
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string SystemName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a product identifier that is required by this customer role. 
        /// A customer is added to this customer role once a specified product is purchased.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int PurchasedWithProductId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the permission records
        /// </summary>
        public virtual  ICollection<PermissionRecord> PermissionRecords
        {
            get { return _permissionRecords ?? (_permissionRecords = new List<PermissionRecord>()); }
            protected set { _permissionRecords = value; }
        }
    }
```

CustomerMap.cs:

```
 public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
    {
        public CustomerMap()
        {
            Table("Customer");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");                
            Map(x => x.CustomerGuid).Column("CustomerGuid").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Username).Column("Username").Length(1000);
            Map(x => x.Email).Column("Email").Length(1000);
            Map(x => x.Password).Column("Password");
            Map(x => x.PasswordFormatId).Column("PasswordFormatId").Not.Nullable().Precision(10);
            Map(x => x.PasswordSalt).Column("PasswordSalt");
            Map(x => x.AdminComment).Column("AdminComment");
            Map(x => x.IsTaxExempt).Column("IsTaxExempt").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.AffiliateId).Column("AffiliateId").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.VendorId).Column("VendorId").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Active).Column("Active").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Deleted).Column("Deleted").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.IsSystemAccount).Column("IsSystemAccount").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.SystemName);
            Map(x => x.LastIpAddress);
            Map(x => x.CreatedOnUtc).Column("CreatedOnUtc").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.LastLoginDateUtc).Column("LastLoginDateUtc");
            Map(x => x.LastActivityDateUtc).Column("LastActivityDateUtc");
            References(x => x.BillingAddress).Column("BillingAddress_Id");
            References(x => x.ShippingAddress).Column("ShippingAddress_Id");

        }


    }
```

CustomerRoleMap.cs:

```
public class CustomerRoleMap : ClassMap<CustomerRole>
    {
        public CustomerRoleMap()
        {
            Table("CustomerRole");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
            Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable().Length(255);
            Map(x => x.FreeShipping).Column("FreeShipping").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.TaxExempt).Column("TaxExempt").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.Active).Column("Active").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.IsSystemRole).Column("IsSystemRole").Not.Nullable();
            Map(x => x.SystemName).Column("SystemName").Length(255);
            Map(x => x.PurchasedWithProductId).Column("PurchasedWithProductId").Not.Nullable().Precision(10);

            HasMany<CustomerRole>(x => x.Id).Table("Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping").KeyColumn("CustomerRole_Id");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the two FK's in the table " Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping." , you do ~not need a separate mapping for this table.

If your " Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping." has its own SurrogateKey, or any other columns besides the two FK's...you will need a mapping (and a poco/pojo class for this mapping).

Customer Mapping

```
        /* the below is how to do it without a surogatekey on the link table */
        HasManyToMany<CustRoleNHEntity>(x => x.CustRoles)
       .Table("Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping")
            .ParentKeyColumns.Add("AbcCustomerUUID", p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_CustRole_Unique").Index("IX_ABC123"))
            .ChildKeyColumns.Add("AbcCustRoleUUID", p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_CustRole_Unique"))
            .Cascade.None()
            ;
```

CustRole Mapping

```
        /* the below is how to do it without a surogatekey on the link table */
        HasManyToMany<CustomerNHEntity>(x => x.MyCustomers) /* I think this is missing on the POCO */
       .Table("Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping")
            .ParentKeyColumns.Add("AbcCustRoleUUID", p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_CustRole_Unique").Index("IX_ABC123"))
            .ChildKeyColumns.Add("AbcCustomerUUID", p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_CustRole_Unique"))
            .Cascade.None()
            ;
```

You need an ICollection of Customers on the CustomerRole poco/pojo, which I call "MyCustomers" in the CustRole mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain the unique key value that what we have in this. Also the index property that we need to take according to our model.As I am not getting you for the following points in both the mapping(CustomerMap & CustomerRoleMap) :
1) p => p.UniqueKey("Emp_CustRole_Unique") 
2) Index("IX_ABC123").

Comment: Can you please help me for this. So that I can move further on this task.